# According to Presbyterianism, is there salvation available for Adam and Eve?

Tags: adam-and-eve, presbyterianism

Generally, when I talk to people from other denominations about Adam and Eve, I get the impression that they're not highly liked people.

Do Presbyterians believe there's salvation available to Adam and Eve?

Comment: I would up-vote your question except that it would take hours, if not days, of research to find out what Catholics (Eastern and Western) and Protestants (of which there are hundreds of denominations) have to say about Adam and Eve.  Added to that, you want answers on four points. Might I suggest you simplify things by (for example) sticking to question 4 alone, and also request answers from specific denominations.  You would then be able to compare what they say, rather than getting people to do intensive research across the Christian spectrum for your benefit. Your question is too complex.

Comment: The Bible tells us very little about them, other than their one big moment, when they brought sin into the world. So it's natural that Christians might speak negatively to them. But it's also natural that Christians are agnostic about anything the Bible doesn't say about them, like their final salvation state. So most denominations would say that it's possible they were saved. Why wouldn't they? It would be remarkable if any denomination said it was impossible for them to be saved!

Comment: The ground was cursed for Adam's sake.  Having internalized the temptation to be like God, humanity would never be able to respond properly to God in a condition of paradise.  Now that humanity has fallen it is through difficulty that we cry out to God.  God cursed His creation and expelled Adam and Eve from paradise as an act of deep love.  If they had eaten from the Tree of Life and solidified their fallen condition then God's sacrifice of His Son would have been ineffectual.  God expelled them so that they could be saved!  Adam and Eve are dearly loved by God.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. tbh I put down all 4 points because I wasn't sure whether or not this was a so-obvious-there's-no-point-asking type of question - I was hoping to give it some meat if it was. I'm not sure what to do about specifying a denomination though - I'm not really interested in any particular denomination's answer. Perhaps that fact alone dooms this question. However, do you think point #4, aimed at a specific denomination, would be a question people might want to answer? I'd rather adjust this into a useful question for someone than just delete it.

Comment: I posted a response to this question but when it was time to post it, the question had been narrowed down to presbyterianism. If I find a source to add in, I may undelete it?

Comment: [This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1399/6071) has answers showing Catholics and Orthodox teach they were saved. The more interesting question would be if there are any denominations which say Adam and Eve did not have the option of salvation after they sinned.

Comment: @ken thanks. Sorry, the close votes were coming in and I agreed with the feedback that the question was too broad for the site. I made a quick change. I'd be interested in your answer, but ya, for the sake of fitting into the site's structure, maybe find a source, like you mentioned.

Comment: @curiousdannii that would be interesting! Will it cause me problems to be changing my question again? I'd be fine with you asking that question separately, if that's easier.

Comment: Maybe this one could be changed to ask for an overview of how the denominations generally regard Adam and Eve, and then a second question could be asked if any say they couldn't be saved.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'll leave this one as-is and ask a second question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**According to Presbyterianism, is there salvation available for Adam and Eve?**

The short response is that it is **probable that Adam and Eve were saved**.

The Bible does not explicitly state whether Adam and Eve went to heaven.  While Adam and Eve later serve as examples of sinful failure in the rest of Scripture, (Adam in Job 31:33; Hosea 6:7; Rom. 5:12-14; 1 Cor. 15:21-22 and Eve in 2 Cor. 11:3; 1 Tim. 2:13-14) we do know at least two instances later in the Genesis narrative where Eve exhibited faith in God.

Some allow the possibility in the affirmative.

The Westminster Confession of Faith admits that Adam was saved. See this [article](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SXjUAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA543&lpg=PA543&dq=presbyterianism%20%20adam%20and%20eve%20saved&source=bl&ots=fXHpDz_tvs&sig=ACfU3U3RfApPlWvCxgI27_f8VFVc3bnomg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5t7DKwtHoAhUUJTQIHekoBHAQ6AEwDXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=presbyterianism%20%20adam%20and%20eve%20saved&f=false) in **The Presbyterian Review**.

Some Presbyterians look on the persons of Adam and Eve as simply mythological persons, such as seen [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=_m7UAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=presbyterianism%20venerate%20adam%20and%20eve&source=bl&ots=RH-5N0xGBQ&sig=ACfU3U126_cwdsmsBhaZC222zBxoiq3BzA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgo-z8wNHoAhWmCjQIHfHyDAUQ6AEwCXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=presbyterianism%20venerate%20adam%20and%20eve&f=false). After all snakes do not converse with people!

[The Irish Presbyterian Mind](https://books.google.ca/books?id=h0VvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=According%20to%20Presbyterianism,%20is%20there%20salvation%20available%20for%20Adam%20and%20Eve?&source=bl&ots=QpeEcsCppb&sig=ACfU3U3ruDxX5V0kinP1E7_wJcDC282WOg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF3-_RuNHoAhVNHjQIHewqDtwQ6AEwC3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=According%20to%20Presbyterianism%2C%20is%20there%20salvation%20available%20for%20Adam%20and%20Eve%3F&f=false) states the following:

> The Covenant of Works described Adam as head of the human race who gained God’s favour through perfect obedience. As a consequence of the disobedience of Adam and Eve, the guilt and punishment for sin were imputed to humanity, **who were unable to save themselves from their inherent rebellion against God.** God in his grace then entered into a Covenant of Grace that was administered differently in the Old and New Testament.

***Now follows the response to the question as it was originally worded prior to it being edited to include only a Presbyterian response.***

**In general the feelings towards Adam and Eve in other denominations are not at all negative.**

The short answer is that both **Adam and Eve are saved**.

Both Adam and Eve are venerated in the Catholic Church, Orthodox Church, Oriental Church and other denominations. Both worked out their salvation through prayer, faith and penance for their transgressions.

They are commemorated as saints in the Orthodox Church in mid December.

> In the Orthodox Church Adam and Eve are counted among the saints and commemorated on the Sunday of the Holy Forefathers, falling between December 11th and 17th. The Synaxarion entry for this Sunday reads:
>
> > Commemoration of Adam and Eve, the first-formed.

Even some Protestant Reformed Church believe that Adan and Eve are saved.

> First, we can say that Eve was saved. God said to the serpent, who is Satan (Rev. 1 2:9), "I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel" (Gen. 3:15). The “woman" is Eve (cf. 3:1-2, 4, 6, 12-13, 16). Through the Fall, Adam and Eve allied themselves with Satan and joined him in his hatred against God. When God put enmity between Satan and the "woman," Eve, He was restoring the covenant friendship that He had with her before the Fall. Viewed in this light, the "coats of skins" (3:21), which the Lord made and with which He clothed her, speak of the garments of salvation, as the church has traditionally taught. It comes as no surprise that Eve confesses that the sons she later bares came to her from the hand of the Almighty (4:1, 25). Thus God's coming to find Eve (3:8ff.) speaks of His graciously coming to seek and to save that which was lost (cf. Luke 19:10). Clearly, Eve was saved.
>
> Second, nor only Eve but also Adam was saved. Eve is prominent in acknowledging that God gave her the birth of Cain and Seth (Gen. 4:1, 25), but are we to think that Adam played no role in naming his sons and thus in confessing Jehovah as the God who gives life? Similarly, God clothed not only Eve but also Adam in those "coats of skins" (3:21) that betoken salvation. Furthermore, God came not only to Eve but also to Adam to show them their sin and misery that He might deliver them (3:8ff.). - [The Salvation of Adam and Eve](http://www.prca.org/resources/publications/cr-news/item/910-the-salvation-of-adam-and-eve)

According to the Catholic Church, Adam and Eve are in heaven and considered saints; thus they are held in high regard.

How can any Christian blame Adam And Eve for anything that befalls human nature or human society. Would we have done better in their situation. I guess that would include the actual Coronavirus-19 situation.

If fact the Catholic Church has a great respect for our first parents.

During the Easter Vigil, the Catholic Church will chant (sing) the traditional Easter Proclamation hymn of the [Exsultet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exsultet).

The Exsultet expresses the Church's belief that this is the same night in which the ancient Jews were liberated from their bondage under the Egyptians, as well as honouring Adam (in an indirect manner).

> O certe necessárium Adæ peccátum,
>   quod Christi morte delétum est!
>
> O felix culpa,
>   quæ talem ac tantum méruit habére Redemptórem!

The English equivalent could be translated as such:

> O truly necessary sin of Adam,
>   destroyed completely by the Death of Christ!
>
> O happy fault
>   that earned for us so great, so glorious a Redeemer!

As I mentioned above, according to Catholicism, both Adam and Eve are saints. How could there be any negativity in all this?

> It is true that there are no feast days for Old Testament saints in the Church's universal calendar.
>
> In the beginning, only martyrs for Christ were honored on the anniversary of their deaths. Soon, feast days for our Blessed Mother began to be observed. This gradual process of development in no way implied we should not ask Old Testament saints to intercede for us.
>
> In fact, the Church does in various ways venerate and ask for the intercession of Old Testament saints.
>
> In 1600 a liturgical book, the Roman Martyrology, listed all the saints whom the Church had officially recognized up to that point. This listing includes large numbers of saints who do not appear in the Church's general calendar.
>
> The Roman Martyrology remembers, among others, the following Old Testament saints: the prophet Habakkuk (Jan. 15); Isaiah (July 6); Daniel and Elias/Elijah (July 20 and 21); the seven Maccabees and their mother (Aug. 17); Abraham (Oct. 9); and King David (Dec. 29).
>
> Meanwhile, in the litanies of the saints we invoke the prayers of "all holy patriarchs and prophets," who are of course Old Testament saints. - [Old Testament Saints?](https://www.osv.com/More/MediaRoom/Item/TabId/901/ArtMID/13959/ArticleID/16735/Old-Testament-Saints.aspx)

The feast of Adam and Eve is December 24!

> As we have said elsewhere, Adam and Eve are not called saints in ordinary reference, historical or scriptural. But they may be called saints on their feast day, which is the vigil of Christmas, because we know from sound Catholic tradition that they repented of their great sin, lived lives of holiness and are now in Heaven. Adam is the father of the human race. Eve, his wife, was formed from Adam’s body. All of us have descended from these two. Adam was created in a state of paradisal innocence, with no human frailties or weaknesses. Adam sinned by disobeying the command of God not to eat a forbidden fruit. The whole human race inherited original sin because of Adam. Adam personally repented. Adam lived for 930 years. By his sorrow, his contrition, his pleading and his love, Adam finally won God’s full forgiveness for himself. Adam died and went to the Limbo of the Just, which is called “hell” in the Apostles’ Creed. This was not the hell of the damned. It was the place where the Just had to wait for the coming of Christ.... Adam’s feast is the vigil of Christmas, which is also the feast of Eve, his wife, who is with him in Heaven. - [Saint Adam and Saint Eve (First Age of the world)](https://catholicism.org/saint-adam-and-saint-eve-first-age-of-the-world.html)

[Adam the Patriarch](http://catholicsaints.info/adam-the-patriarch/) is one of the patron saints of gardeners and tailors.

[Eve the Matriarch](http://catholicsaints.info/eve-the-matriarch/)is one of the Patron saints of tailors also.

Adam and Eve's Feastday is Christmas Eve (December 24)

[image: Adam and Eve by Albrecht Curer]

[Adam and Eve by Albrecht Curer](http://www.medadvocates.org/holy_mole/dec/dec_24.htm)

**Sancti Ada et Eva, orate pro nobis.**

For those who desire to honour Adam and Eve in a small way, why not try the [**Adam and Eve Pudding**](http://www.medadvocates.org/holy_mole/dec/dec_24.htm) someday! Make it a tradition if you want!

Comment: That quote from the Irish Presbyterian Mind is I think referring just to their sin in the fall, not the rest of their lives. For Adam and Eve to not have the possibility of salvation would go against every other aspect of the Gospel.

Comment: @curiousdannii Possibly, it is ambiguous. My answer may need more tweaking!

Comment: +1 for the recepie for the Adam and Eve Pudding - sounds yummy!

Comment: Thank you for that @ken, and for keeping the part answering the original question. I find it interesting how other Christians view Adam and Eve, but typically as soon as they hear that I'm LDS the language quickly turns negative about Adam and Eve. I really appreciate this! It's fantastic! It gives me lots to study more about.

Comment: @Lesley When social distancing is over maybe we can party with it?